# Android - what busy marker for individual rows in ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, busy-cursor

I have android application with ListView, where each row has own "refresh" button. Refreshing content is based on asynchronous http call, so until it completes (or timeout) I'd like to display some kind of graphical "busy" marker in each affected (clicked) row. What is best practice to do it? I see animated gifs - i.e. ones with rotating circle - does not animate on Android. So far I tried RotateAnimation on static image, it looks OK but it's not what people are accustomed to.

Is there any better way to mark individual row in ListView as being updated? 
Target SDK is so far 1.5.

Comment: What do you think "people are accustomed to"?

Comment: AJAX Web apps typically uses rotating circle, Android apps uses general busy marker in title bar or modal window with progress bar or something. Updating single row on demand is rare case but makes sense in my app, so I'm looking for intuitive busy marker for such use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do animated gifs

- Movie.decodeStream if your firmware version supports it
- or use a [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) as in an <animation-list> on a few images from the image set

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation

Comment: Note for readers - Frame Animation is more Drawable than Animation, set it with ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim); and clear with setImageDrawable(null);

Answer (score 1):

I'd just stick with what you have: a `RotateAnimation`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I decided to stick with well known rotating circle from http://www.ajaxload.info/

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like "Updating..." Android 1.5 [Settings] [Applications] [Manage Applications] uses this for "Computing..." memory while it builds the list of applications.